# Google App Engine Projection Query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model like this:

```
class Users(db.Model):
   email = db.EmailProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
   user_name = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
   api_key = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
   active = db.BooleanProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
   real_name = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)
   ...etc
```

When I tried to make a query like this:

```
user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT email, api_key, active FROM Users WHERE user_name = :1", username).get()
```

It's returning None, but when I use this query:

```
user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_name = :1", username).get()
```

It's ok, returns everything. But why I can't use the first query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot project unindexed properties. As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection)

> There are some limitations on what properties can be projected:
>   You can only project indexed properties. This means that projecting Text, Blob or other properties explicitly marked as unindexed is not supported.

You can find out what indexes are required by running your query in the Datastore Viewer in the Admin Console.

Comment: Hm. I think it would be nice if this query was rejected instead of silently returning nothing.  I filed a bug for the corresponding issue in NDB: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=189&thanks=189&ts=1339860107

Comment: From the SDK version 1.7.0, at least for Windows, even unindexed properties can be queried with projection.

Comment: As of 1.9, you can't project unindexed properties, which is a shame.